# Wireless and trackpad disabled in Ubuntu 13.04 after update

Tags: wireless, networking, trackpad

Last week on Ubuntu 13.04, I ran a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Everything seemed fine until I rebooted. Suddenly, my trackpad stopped functioning, and I couldn't view available wireless networks anymore. I've run this command many times to update packages, and I have no idea how to go about diagnosing the problem. I also don't have access to a wired network to see if running another update fixes the issue. I do have a live USB but wouldn't know how to go about using it to resolve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Posting the solution I found for the sake of others:

I checked and could not find the device for either my trackpad or my wireless card, so I decided to try reinstalling the driver. I came across http://kuscsik.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-install-intel-4965-wireless.html which explained how to install the driver for my computer (Dell Inspiron 1720). I only had to run the one command `sudo modprobe iwl4965`, and my wifi immediately started working again. I ran `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`, rebooted, and then the trackpad worked perfectly as well.

Comment: Sorry I have to downvote this. That guide is **really old**. It even mentions at the top: `This guide is not actual anymore. Just update to the latest Ubuntu Gutsy and boot with the generic kernel.` Your Intel wireless 4965 is supported perfectly fine in the current Ubuntu releases. Your issue must have another cause. My best guess is that you were running in a slight bug and you just needed to pull in the regular updates, reboot and it would have been all fine.